`l3build` unit tests on expansion of a macro
What is the good way to test the expansion of a macro? In the following test, I would like to check if the full expansion of \tdocinEN{OK?} is the same as the one of \tdocquote{OK?} in English.
\documentclass{tutodoc}

\input{regression-test}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\START

\BEGINTEST{Macros}
    \ASSERT{\tdocinEN{OK?}}{\tdocquote{OK?} in English}
\ENDTEST

\OMIT

\end{document}

Internally, I have :
\NewDocumentCommand{\tdocinEN}{s m}{%
  \tdocquote{#2}%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{% No star used.
    \tutodoc@trans@in@EN{}%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tutodoc@trans@in@EN}{m}{#1 in English}

Hoping that I'm not the new victim of the spurious spaces...
PS: my code is strange and it will be fixed. So don't judge the definitions of the commands.

your command is not expandable, so the only way to see what is doing is to execute e.g. in a box and then to show the box.

You mean to test the PDF output. That's it?

No, use \showoutput or something like that.

or \showbox or \box_show:N or similar. (if you just want to show the box and nothing else.)

@DavidCarlisle This class is on CTAN, last update: 2024-10-19.

is LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 95, version                \2023-09-07' of package marginnote,
but only version
`2018/08/09 1.4b non floating margin notes for LaTeX'
is available.`
expected?

No. I will investigate this as soon as possible. :~!

As the commands are not expandable you want to show their typeset results are the same not their expansion, something like
\documentclass{tutodoc}

\input{regression-test}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\START

\BEGINTEST{Macros}
\sbox0{\tdocinEN{OK?}}
\sbox2{\tdocquote{OK?} in English}
\SEPARATOR
\showbox0
\SEPARATOR
\showbox2
\SEPARATOR
\ENDTEST

\OMIT

\end{document}

Note this can not check at run-time that the two results are the same, but the idea is you check once before saving your .tlg and if anything later changes you will be alerted.
Actually they are not the same as you can see already from the sizes of box0 and box2
> \box0=
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x76.74721
....
> \box2=
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x79.10834

The difference being e or E in english
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
...
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 E


You're right, and this test shows a programming error in the actual CTAN version. Tests are so useful. :-)

For the 1st check, I'm going to do it by coding a dedicated Lua plugin of l3build. Thanks for all!

I have added a draft Lua code to automate the validation.

@projetmbc thanks. in practice if the boxes are different they probably have different size so just making an assert on \wd0=\wd2 would catch most cases (along with checking if the output changes as above) but the lua test is quite nice too

The script will be maintained at https://github.com/bc-tools/for-latex/tree/l3build_xtras/l3build-xtras/src .
Original answer
Here is a basic way to validate the outputs by using l3build sbunit NAME_OF_MY_TESTFILE.
How to write a test file
You can simply use \TYPE{SB-TESTED} and \TYPE{SB-WANTED} if you prefer.
\documentclass{tutodoc}

\input{regression-test}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\START

\BEGINTEST{Macros}

\sbox0{\tdocinEN{OK?}}
\sbox2{\tdocquote{OK?} in English}

\TYPE{SB-TESTED "inEn"}
\showbox0

\TYPE{SB-WANTED "inEn"}
\showbox2

\ENDTEST

\OMIT

\end{document}

Code for build.lua
This is a functional version with useful explanations on Unix using the diff tool.
-------------------
-- GENERAL TOOLS --
-------------------

function raise(kind, message)
    print("")
    print(kind .. ".ERROR! " .. message)

    return 1
end

-----------------
-- CMD OPTIONS --
-----------------

-- UNIT TESTS: AUTO VALIDATIONS OF [S]HOW[B]OX COMPARISONS --

-- Source for l3build use of \showbox: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729463/6880

cmd_option = "sbunit"

TAG_CHECK  = "check"
TAG_IGNORE = "standard"
TAG_TEST   = "test"

TAG_L3BUILD_BOX_START = "> \\box"
TAG_L3BUILD_BOX_END   = "! OK."

DIFF_OPTION_SIDE_BY_SIDE  = "-y"
DIFF_OPTION_FULL_ONE_PAGE = "-u"

function checkSBUNIT(xtra_args)
    if xtra_args == nil or #xtra_args ~= 1
    then
        return raise(
            "IO",
            "One single test file name needed!"
        )
    end

    print("SHOWBOX COMPARISON validation.")

    local testfilename = xtra_args[1]
    local logfile      = testfilename .. ".log"

    local file  = io.open(testdir .. "/" .. logfile)
    local lines = file:lines()

    local nbline = 0

    local nbtests = 0
    local kind    = TAG_IGNORE

    local line_test = -1
    local log_test  = ""

    local line_check = -1
    local log_check  = ""

    for line in lines
    do
        nbline    = nbline + 1
        startline = string.sub(line, 1, 9)

        if startline == "SB-TESTED"
        then
            line_test = nbline
            kind      = TAG_TEST
            catego    = string.sub(line, 11, -1)

        elseif startline == "SB-WANTED"
        then
            if catego ~= string.sub(line, 11, -1)
            then
                return raise(
                    "FORMAT",
                    "Showbox checker without a showbox tested: see line "
                    .. nbline ..
                    " in the log file. Tested? Same category?"
                )
            end


            line_check = nbline
            kind       = TAG_CHECK

        elseif line == TAG_L3BUILD_BOX_END
        then
            if kind == TAG_CHECK
            then
                error_code = _compareSBUNIT(
                    catego,
                    line_test , log_test,
                    line_check, log_check
                )

                if error_code == 1
                then
                    return error_code
                end

                if error_code == false
                then
                    return raise(
                        "TEST",
                        "Validation has failed!"
                    )
                end
            end

            kind = TAG_IGNORE

        elseif string.sub(line, 0, 6) ~= TAG_L3BUILD_BOX_START
        then
            if kind == TAG_TEST
            then
                log_test = log_test .. "\n" .. line

            elseif kind == TAG_CHECK
            then
                log_check = log_check .. "\n" .. line
            end
        end
    end

    print("\nSuccessful validation.")
    return 0
end


target_list[cmd_option] = {
    func = checkSBUNIT,
    desc = "Check showbox comparison unit test",
--   pre = function(xtra_args)
--   end
}


function _compareSBUNIT(
    catego,
    line_test , log_test,
    line_check, log_check
)
    local what   = "Showbox " .. catego

-- Happy day!
    if log_test == log_check
    then
        result = true

        print("    + " .. what .. " [OK]")

        return true
    end

-- Chaos day...
    print("    + " .. what .. " [KO]")

    print("LOG FILE. Test starts at line " .. line_test .. ".")
    print("          Check starts at line " .. line_check .. ".")

    io.write("UNIX ONLY. Do you want to `diff` the contents (y/n)? ")
    answer = io.read()

    if answer == "y"
    then
        local logtestfile_name = "build/test/" .. "@_@test_@_l3build@_@"
        local logtestfile      = io.open(logtestfile_name, "w")

        if logtestfile == nil
        then
            return raise(
                "IO",
                "Temp file ''"
                .. logtestfile_name ..
                "'' can't be created."
            )
        end

        local logcheckfile_name = "build/test/" .."@_@check_@_l3build@_@"
        local logcheckfile      = io.open(logcheckfile_name, "w")

        if logcheckfile == nil
        then
            os.remove(logtestfile)

            return raise(
                "IO",
                "Temp file ''"
                .. logcheckfile_name ..
                "'' can't be created."
            )
        end

        logtestfile:write(log_test)
        logcheckfile:write(log_check)

        local iostream = assert(
            io.popen(
                "diff "
                .. DIFF_OPTION_FULL_ONE_PAGE ..
                " "
                .. logtestfile_name ..
                " "
                .. logcheckfile_name,
                'r'
            )
        )

        local infos = assert(iostream:read('a'))

        iostream:close()

        infos = string.gsub(infos, '^%s+', '')
        infos = string.gsub(infos, '%s+$', '')

        print("`diff -u test check` gives:")
        print("")

        print(infos)

        os.remove(logtestfile_name)
        os.remove(logcheckfile_name)
    end

    return false
end

One possible SHORT output
SHOWBOX COMPARISON validation.
    + Showbox "inEn" [KO]

LOG FILE. Test starts at line 733.
          Check starts at line 763.

One possible FULL output (using diff)
SHOWBOX COMPARISON validation.
    + Showbox "inEn" [KO]

LOG FILE. Test starts at line 733.
          Check starts at line 763.

UNIX ONLY. Do you want to `diff` the contents (y/n)? y
`diff -u test check` gives:

--- build/test/@_@test_@_l3build@_@ 2024-10-27 21:44:43.000000000 +0100
+++ build/test/@_@check_@_l3build@_@    2024-10-27 21:44:43.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@

-\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x79.10834
+\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x81.74725
 .\pdfcolorstack 0 push {0 g 0 G}
 .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 \
 .\penalty 10000
@@ -11,10 +11,12 @@
 .\kern 1.22499
 .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 "
 .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
+.\kern 1.66672
+.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
 .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
 .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
 .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
-.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 E
+.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
 .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
 .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
 .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l

TEST.ERROR! Validation has failed!


I think you could make this cross-platform, if you wanted, by using the approach l3build uses for diff. (maybe?)

In my case, the standard diff is more useful.

I certainly prefer standard diff's output, but it does mean windows users can't compile your code ....

There are still useful information in case of failure. I have updated my answer.
